# How to display the results in pdf in same order as the chunks in the .RNW file

Tags: r, knitr

I'm using .RNW file from knitr (RStudio, Rversion 3.1) and would like to get the output in a pdf file in the same order as the chunks are in the .RNW file. I'm not writing an article but am analyzing data producing a lot of output.
As I'm writing a little text between the chunks the pdf file is messed up to optimize information (not too many empty spaces) on the pages.

Is there a option available to force the print order?

Thanks in advance,
Regards, Hans

Here is the code I'm using

```
<<summary2, echo=FALSE, results=tex>>=
library(xtable)
attach(dataVoor)
tab <- table(PathEM,NTpathEm)
xtable(tab, caption = c("Relatie path EM en NT-path EM"))
... several tab and xtable as above in the same chunck....
detach(dataVoor)
@

\subsection*{Analyse van risicofactoren voor infectie NA spenen}

<<ReadData2, echo=FALSE>>=
dataNa <- read.delim("~/datasetNa.txt")
@

<<summaryNa2, echo=FALSE, results=verbatim>>=
attach(dataNa)
names(dataNa)
summary(dataNa)
@
```

So several xtables are placed in between the summary of dataNA

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific (e.g., show us an example Rnw document). The PDF should be in the same order as the original file.

Comment: Part of the code is as follows
<<summary2, echo=FALSE, results=tex>>=
library(xtable)
attach(dataVoor)
tab <- table(PathEM,NTpathEm)
xtable(tab))

tab <- table(PathEM,huisvesting.indiv)
xtable(tab, caption = c("relatie path EM en huisvesting-indiv"))
 ... several tables more ...

detach(dataVoor)
@

\subsection*{Analyse van risicofactoren voor infectie NA spenen}

<<ReadData2, echo=FALSE>>=
setwd("~/Consultaties/TinevWerven2014_08")
dataNa <- read.delim("~/datasetNa.txt")
@
<<summaryNa2, echo=FALSE, results=verbatim>>=
summary(dataNa)
@
Some of the tables are positioned in the summary dataNA

Comment: Always post code as an *edit* to your question, not as a comment. Code is comments is unreadable.

Comment: positioning floats exactly where you want is always a headache with latex. It's really a latex question.

Answer (score 0):

I did find some solution by specifying argument table.placement in the print function of xtable:

- print(xtable(tab, digits=0, caption = c("Frequency table of Gender per Zoba")), caption.placement="top", table.placement = getOption("xtable.table.placement", "h!"))

Now the results in the pdf are in the same order as in the program was specified.
Thanks for replying on my question.